# Subversion Update Issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm getting the following error when I try to update my repository. Can someone explain what it means?

Command: Update
Error: URL
Error: 'http://mysvn/foo'
Error: of existing directory
Error: 'C:\SVN\MyProj\NinjectModules\Models' does not match
Error: expected URL 'http://mysvn/foo/NinjectModules/Models'
Finished!:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of error message is usually associated with [letter casing errors in the svn repository](http://www.rowanhanna.com/blog/2011/02/svn-does-not-match-expected-url/). Perhaps your svn is installed on a Linux machine and there you have two identical folders:

```
(..)/mysvn/foo
(..)/MySVN/Foo
```

And initially SVN checks out `MySVN/Foo` and it doesn't find the `\NinjectModules\Models` folder because it is in `/mysvn/foo` location

Answer (score 9):

It is not *always* a case problem

I encountered this error message due to improper directory moving that scrambled the svn data. The way I fixed it was to delete the working copy directory and then svn update that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason might be migration from including some files with `svn:externals` property to actually adding the files to your repository.

That is, when between two updates of your working copy someone does following:

```
#svn up removes local copies of external resources when svn:externals is deleted
#so we need a backup
cp -R library/resource /backup
svn propdel 'svn:externals' library
svn up
cp -R /backup/resource library
svn add library/resource
svn commit -m "this will break other working copies, but we have the resource in our repo now"
```

When you try to `svn update` your wc, you will get following message:

```
svn: URL 'svn://path.to/external/resource' of existing directory 
'library/resource' does not match expected URL 'svn://my.own.repository/library/resource'
```

In such case the solution is as usual - remove the `library` directory of the working copy and do `svn up` to restore it in its current state.

Remeber to back up your local changes somewhere