# svn: URL <foo> of existing dierctory <foo> does not match expected URL <foo>

Tags: svn

Ok I have seen this and still do not know how to solve without deleting my current folder and getting new. but there must be a better solution.  Here is my exact error:

`svn: URL 'http://moray.aniworld.local:8080/svn/Devon/trunk/IncurredCost' of exis
ting directory 'trunk\IncurredCost' does not match expected URL 'http://moray.an
iworld.local:8080/svn/devon/trunk/IncurredCost'`

Note that there are no duplicate directory names in my repository.  How can I fix this so that I can just do "svn update" at the top level and have this one annoying fodler update properly?

Edit:  this is the situation, I have repo foo, with a trunk, and then subfolders d1, d2, d3, and d4.  d1 has alot of binaries  that i don't want to delete and get again (over http and VPN, it's slow).  because the files are there, and in sync already.  I just want to tell svn that everything is OK, no need to get everything all over.

Comment: subversion URLs are case sensitive. Note the difference in your message: *D*evon vs. *d*evon

Comment: there are numerous folders under Devon, and no others have any issues at all when updating from SVN.  So that does not appear to be the issue.

Answer (score 9):

You actually have the same problem as [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834155/subversion-update-issue/6834457#6834457) wich makes this question a duplicate (and it will probably be closed soon for that reason). The problem is that you have on your SVN two folders with the same name but which are of different case. For example: `trunk\IncurredCost` and `trunk\incurredcost`

Comment: But I don't - there is no incurredcost folder anywhere, only IncurredCost, the actual folder, and the repo folder have identical names.  So that post really does not answer the question.

Comment: is your SVN server on a Windows or a Linux based machine ?

Comment: I took a closer look at the error code you highlighted and the source of the error is strictly related to what I said before. The first repository link in the message is `http://moray.aniworld.local:8080/svn/Devon/trunk/IncurredCost
` and the second is `http://moray.aniworld.local:8080/svn/devon/trunk/IncurredCost`. Notice the diferences between these two links: in the first one `Devon` starts with a capital letter and in the second one `devon` starts with lower case. **there's your problem!**

Comment: Ok.  Any idea how to fool this into working?  Like edit props-base by hand and make the "D" lowercase?  Just looking for a solution that is better than delete and get again, since the files are there.

Comment: I am thinking that some file in the .svn folder has this uppercase D, and if I can replace that, then it should work properly.

Comment: ugh, no solution, so just deleted everything and starting with a fresh checkout.  which is a major waste of bandwidth because there are many large binary files that I already had.  I just wanted to synch up with the latest changes.  SVN is all file-based, so there must be some way of tricking it into recognizing folders properly.

Comment: If you are using Tortoise SVN the thing to do is right click on the folder with the problem -> `Repo-Browser` and select the repository with the correct casing; if that (version of the) folder does not exist then you should modify the repository path by hand and hit `Ok`. Sorry for the delay, I do other things in paralel

Comment: after selecting the right repo in the browser, then what?  not check out, not update, but what?  No problem with the delays, as this issue has been nagging me for months.  The lame solution is to dive down into the offending folder and do an update there.

Comment: @JohnPaul let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1900/discussion-between-daniel-williams-and-john-paul)

Comment: (since chat didn't help) Back here.. As I said earlier, go to the `Repo-Browser` and check to see if you have under `\svn` both `Devon` and `devon`. Then to avoid having this problem in the future, you will have to delete from the repository either `devon` or `Devon` folder. You will do that trough the `Repo-Browser`. The problem originates in the fact that you (or somebody else) commited into svn folder `devon` on one (windwos)PC and `Devon` on a different (windows)PC. Svn sees them as two separate folders as it must be compatible with linux.

Comment: As a last effort to help you understand what is it you have to do, I replicated your scenario and produced these snapshots: [`here's how you access Repo-Browser`](http://www.ioanpaul.pirau.ro/stackoverflow/SVNProblem1.jpg) and [`here's what you must do`](http://www.ioanpaul.pirau.ro/stackoverflow/SVNProblem2.jpg). I will keep the JPGs online for a couple of weeks. Good Luck!

Comment: I can browes to http://.../Devon and http://.../devon as well as http://.../DevoN  and I know DevoN never existed.  So the repo browser (Tortise SVN on Windows 7) does not understand case sensitivity.

Comment: Your Repo-Browser works great, and it shows that you misused the SVN if you are using it exclusively on Windows. Again, and for the last time.. if you want to fix your problem **only one of those folders (`Devon` or `devon` or `DevoN`) must remain in your repository**. As long as you will have all three of them or at least two, you will have the same problem on Windows OS. Be sure to make a backup before you delete from the Repo-Browser, and always keep the TRUE folder that you (and the team) work with. JP.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, Ioan Paul might be right. If anywhere in the path is a different spelling. In other words; If anywhere in the path there exists 'Path' and 'path', then you might have a problem for that reason.

This is actually a not subversion problem, but Windows one. I have had this issue in the past. In my case the SVN server is running on Linux. Some developers are working on Windows and some on Macs. One day, a developer on a Mac created file with the name, 'File' and successfully committed it to SVN. The problem was that the repo already had a file named 'file', but from SVN's perspective and from Linux's perspective, that is absolutely fine. It is also ok from a Mac point of view. However, Windows doesn't know what to do when it sees 'file' and 'File'.

Comment: To the moderator/other reviews. I've just accidentally marked this as spam, it is not...! The answer could do with being made a bit more clearer though.